# Compactness theory for vicinity-based version of Ramsey theory

Tags: compactness, ramsey-theory

A set of lecture notes has claimed that:

> The infinite version of Ramsey theorem implies the finite version by
>   means of compactness theorem: $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}, \exists
> > n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that every finite graph with at least $n$
>   vertices contains a clique of size $k$ or an independent set of size
>   $k$.

I've found Brian's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151396/confusion-regarding-compactness-theorem), where the relation between infinite and finite versions by compactness theorem is explained based on the coloring derivation of Ramsey theorem.

I'm wondering how one can define the $\Sigma$ set of sentences (and its extension to be used by compactness theorem) for the aforesaid claim based on vicinity notions like clique and independent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're asking how to go from colorings to cliques/independences. These are actually the same thing:

- Given a graph $G$ on a set $X$, we get a 2-coloring $C_G$ of pairs of elements of $X$ given by $C_G(\{a, b\})=1$ iff there is an edge between $a$ and $b$ in $G$.
- Given a 2-coloring $C$ of pairs of elements of $X$, we get a graph $G_C$ on $X$ by placing an edge between $a$ and $b$ exactly when $a\not=b$ and $C(\{a, b\})=1$.

This gives you a method for translating everything from one language to another. For example, if we equate graphs/colorings in this way, then a clique is exactly a homogeneous set for the color $1$, and an independent set is a homogeneous set for the color $0$.

Comment: I am actually curious about the role of compactness theorem in such translation. I mean, what is the approach to show that infinite version implies the finite version by compactness theorem?

Comment: @Roboticist I don't quite understand. Compactness plays no role in this translation. Compactness works the same way for cliques/independences as it does for colorings: replace "clique" with "homogeneous set for color $1$" and "independent set" with "homogeneous set for color $0$."

Comment: It's clear to me now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Roboticist No problem, glad to help!