# Implication of finite from infinite Ramsey theorem by contrapositive!

Tags: logic, compactness

This question is considerably related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2203205/compactness-theory-for-vicinity-based-version-of-ramsey-theory).

As a matter of fact, I need to show that:

> Using the Compactness Theorem, show that the Infinite Ramsey Theorem
> implies the following Finite Ramsey Theorem: $\forall k \in
> > \mathbb{N}$, $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ (depending on $k$) such that
> every finite graph with at least $n$ vertices contains a clique of
> size $k$ or an independent set of size $k$.

According to @Noah's guidance, I just tried to prove the case with bridging between coloring version of the theory and vicinity-based one (based on cliques and independent sets).

My instructor has confirmed the validity of my proof but just commented on that there is a better approach by contrapositive (that I can't understand how it does work). As he said, **I need to assume that the Finite Ramsey Theorem is false, and show that the Infinite Ramsey Theorem is false using the Compactness Theorem (i.e. construct an infinite graph G with no infinite clique and no infinite independent set).**

It's confusing to me as I have no idea how one can use the Compactness Theorem to find a contrapositive.

Could you please enlighten me about this method of proof?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4678343/30229) has a proof of the finite Ramsey theorem from the infinite Ramsey Theorem via propositional compactness. For $p=r=2$ there it is essentially what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the idea. Fix some $n$ which witnesses that Finite Ramsey's Theorem fails - that is, that there are arbitrarily large finite graphs with no size-$n$ cliques or independent sets. In the language of graphs, the sentence $\kappa_n$="$\forall x_1...x_n(\bigvee_{1\le i<j\le n}\neg R(x_i, x_j))$" asserts the nonexistence of a clique of size $n$. Now:

- Can you find a similar sentence $\alpha_n$ asserting the nonexistence of an independent set of size $n$?
- Can you find a family $\Phi$ of sentences which collectively assert that there are infinitely many vertices?

The idea is that the set $S_n=\{\kappa_n,\alpha_n\}\cup\Phi$ describes graphs with infinitely many vertices and no cliques/independent sets of size $n$. Now, under the assumption that Finite Ramsey's Theorem fails at $n$ as described above, do you see how to argue that $S_n$ has a model, and why the existence of such a model contradicts the Infinite Ramsey's Theorem?

Comment: Could you please check my answers to your considered questions? 
1- "Can you find a similar sentence...?" I think it could be easily defined by removing that negation next to the binary relation $R(x_i,x_j)$ since nonexistence of an independent set implies that every no vertices must be connected (adjacent), i.e. $\alpha_n = "\forall x_1...x_n(\bigvee_{1\le i<j\le n} R(x_i, x_j))$"

Comment: @Roboticist Yup, that's right for (1).

Comment: 3- "...do you see how to argue...?" Every subset of $S_n$ has a model because either of $\alpha_n$, $\kappa_n$ and $\Phi$ has a model. So by the Completeness Theorem, $S_n$ has a model.

Comment: @Roboticist That isn't quite right for (3) - partly because we don't yet know what $\Phi$ is, so we don't yet know what all the finite subsets of $S_n$ *are* (although this will be obvious once we pin down $\Phi$), but mostly because the main part was the *other* half of (3): how the existence of such a model contradicts IRT.

Comment: 4- "...why the existence of such a model contradicts the Infinite Ramsey's Theorem?" Because the infinite version of the theorem says every infinite graph contains an infinite clique or an infinite independent set, but we have found a model that implies an infinite graph might have neither of them, albeit being infinite!

Comment: 2- Actually, I have no idea about this question!

Comment: For (4) you're right. For (2), this is one of those things that looks hard at first, but is easy in retrospect. To start with, can you come up with a *single* sentence that implies that there are *at least three* vertices? (We'll then think about $3\rightarrow\infty$ ...)