Compactness theorem of propositional logic and the Ramsey Theorem
Are there any modern references (books, articles)  about connection of
compactness theorem of propositional logic and the Ramsey Theorem?
Thanks.

You might be interested in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4678018/finite-ramsey-theorem-via-propositional-compactness-infinite-ramsey-theorem
